# Iterating a loop to depending on how many of one number is within another

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Lets say i have a counter, and wish it to increment as many times as their are 100s in 500; so 5
i have

```
saleAmount = 200
points = 0
amount = 100
SaleTotal = saleAmount
for amount in str(SaleTotal):
    points = points + 1

print(points)
```

but it seems to give the wrong answer all the time of 3 points rather than 2, any advice would be appreciated, i also need it to only count 2 lots of 100 if i enter say 240.

Comment: whats your expected output?

Comment: I expect 2, but i get 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your problem you need the operator `/` . This way you can obtain the integer of a division

```
saleAmount = 200
points = 0
amount = 100
SaleTotal = saleAmount
number_lots = SaleTotal / amount
for lots in range(number_lots)
    points += 1
```

This will work for your cases